# Adding directory modules to `py_modules` in setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I am probably making a stupid mistake again. But I can not find it. Even in this extremely small minimum (not) working example...

Folder structure:

```
setup.py
x_module
    __init__.py
    main.py
```

`setup.py` contains

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name= 'setup-test',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules = ['x_module' ],
    entry_points = '''
        [console_scripts]
        x_test=x_module.main:main
    '''
)
```

`__init__.py` is empty

`main.py` contains

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def main():
    print('x_module.main.main() executed')
```

Command line output:

```sh
$ pip install .
Processing /workspaces/setup_py_test
Building wheels for collected packages: setup-test
  Building wheel for setup-test (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for setup-test: filename=setup_test-0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=1263 sha256=52c02b70254467e4d10955dc520b692a320f93c858e77711f77b0ab286f422d5
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-miymlm3k/wheels/a1/08/94/6f5e7ee293420487584919e807df93ea4d84adc23ab40faf00
Successfully built setup-test
Installing collected packages: setup-test
  Attempting uninstall: setup-test
    Found existing installation: setup-test 0.1
    Uninstalling setup-test-0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled setup-test-0.1
Successfully installed setup-test-0.1
$ x_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/x_test", line 5, in <module>
    from x_module.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x_module'
```

The weird thing is that it works in editable mode:

```sh
$ pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///workspaces/setup_py_test
Installing collected packages: setup-test
  Attempting uninstall: setup-test
    Found existing installation: setup-test 0.1
    Uninstalling setup-test-0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled setup-test-0.1
  Running setup.py develop for setup-test
Successfully installed setup-test
$ x_test
x_module.main.main() executed
```

Comment: Replace `py_modules = ['x_module' ],` -> `packages=['x_module' ],`

Comment: @phd facepalm.... thank you so much